# Why when I inherit from 'mother' class, with the access specifier set to PRIVATE, I can't create 'mother' class objects in 'granddaughter' class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Why class mother is inaccessible from class granddaughter if class daughter (from which granddaughter inherits) inherits from class mother with the access specifier set to PRIVATE? I can't create objects nor pointers. Why? What is the logic behind this behavior? What could be the problems if I use a mother object in the granddaughter class? And, connected to this last question, why if class daughter inherits from class mother with the access specifier set to PUBLIC or PROTECTED I can create a mother object into granddaughter class? Do those problems not come back to me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class mother
{
    public:
        mother(){};
};

class daughter : private mother
{
    public:
        daughter(){};
};

class granddaughter : public daughter
{ 
    public:
        granddaughter(){}; // ERROR
        mother* mother; // ERROR
};


int main(void){return 0;}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to inherit like this. Better to just have `class Person`s that point to each other.

Comment: The way you have this set up makes every granddaughter also a daughter but also a mother? right?

Comment: thats a bad class design. A mother , daughter and granddaughter are all the same type. (The daughter is the mother of the granddaughter. What about sisters?) The parent child relationship should be expressed as pointers to mother object and list of child objects

Comment: The question is interesting, and nobody should really care about "design", because the [mcve] illustrates the question perfectly.

Comment: Don't look the class design. I know that it's not good...is an examples. I want understand this behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3047511/560648

Comment: To those complaining about class design: Would you have preferred the names `Base`, `Derived`, and `DoubleDerived`? That would mean that every `DoubleDerived` is also a Base, which is incorrect because nothing derives from that.

Comment: @DanielH: Huh? `Base` and `Derived` is the terminology the standard uses and it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Charles: These are not names to actually be used in a project; they don't describe what the classes _are_. Like the typical `Base`/`Derived` terminology, or the `Foo`/`Bar` terminology, or the `T1`/`T2` terminology, they are for _exposition_, describing the inheritance tree itself. Trying to apply human genealogy to the OP's names is obviously not going to work, but that doesn't mean the design is wrong or even that the names are inappropriate for this question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure, but the names inhibit OP's ability to convey what he means as coherently as possible.

Comment: @Charles: I don't think so; the example is very clear. You're confusing matters with this line of questioning though!

Comment: @Charles I have heard the “child class” terminology almost as much as “derived class”, especially colloquially. I haven’t heard it specifically with female gender before, but that’s common in other places (for example, in biology there are “mother cells” and “daughter cells” even though individual cells have no gender).

Comment: Yes... I understand. @DanielH. I was only hoping to eliminate OP's question all together by suggesting that the intended design didn't match the names.

Comment: Sigh...@Charles next time i will use Disys7, Egst6a and Bdisgsi or similar to name my class 

Answer (score 5):

You can create `mother` pointers and instances. But, due to name resolution rules, `mother` typename will refer to the private base class. To get around that, you can use the fully qualified type name `::mother` to refer to the type as a non-base:

```
class granddaughter : public daughter
{ 
    public:
        ::mother* mother; // NO ERROR
};
```

Comment: Tell your children not to walk my way.

Answer (score 2):

So when you use the name `mother` in class `granddaughter` you get an error like the following:

```
test.cpp:22:9: fatal error: 'mother' is a private member of 'mother'
        mother* mother; // ERROR
        ^
```

In C++, you can refer to the base object using its class name. The compiler gives this lookup precedence over looking up the class from the global scope. Since that particular base class is private you get the error.

To fix this, use the scope-resolution operator `::` to force the compiler to lookup from the global scope:

```
class granddaughter : public daughter
{
    public:
        granddaughter(){};                                                                                                                         
    ::mother* mother;                                                                                                                             

};
```

Comment: What "conflict" do you anticipate?

Comment: I thought I had initially received a compile error for having the data member named `mother`. However upon revisiting I see that I was mistaken. I'll update the post to reflect this. Thanks for pointing it out!