# Private inheritance, return reference to static member of base class

Tags: c++, name-lookup, private-inheritance

I have a simple question regarding inheriting from a class which privately inheriting of a base class, i.e. we have

```
class Base {};
class Heir: private Base {};
class HeirsHeir : public Heir {};
```

In understand that `HeirsHeir` cannot access anything of 'its' `Base`. In particular, it cannot have a method returning a `Base &` reference to itself. But why can't it return a reference to *another* Base object? So why does the following code not compile:

```
class Base {};
class Kid : private Base {};
Base instance;
class Grandkid : public Kid
{
    const Base &GetInstance  () const
    { return instance; }
};
```

At least my compiler (MinGW 5.3, i.e. gcc for Windows) gives

```
error 'class Base Base::Base' is inaccessible at {}; 
error: within this context const Base &getInstance () const
```

For my understanding this doesn't make sense as  I do not call the constructor of Base at this point, but return a reference (to a Base instance).

Note that the error can be fixed by using

```
const ::Base &GetInstance  () const
{ return instance; }
```

which is surely linked to C++03 §11.2/3 (see [[C++ private inheritance and static members/types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047511/c-private-inheritance-and-static-members-types][1]))

> Note: A member of a private base class might be inaccessible as an
>   inherited member name, but accessible directly.

But I do not understand why this is necessary. Can somebody explain it?

Comment: Sorry for switching from Base, Heir, HeirsHeir to Parent, Kid, Grandkid and back again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name lookup finds the injected-class-name `Base` which is injected into `Base` (and thus inherited by `GrandKid`). This is correct, since the injected-class-name is in a closer scope than the namespace-scope name of the class. However, this injected-class-name is not accessible to `GrandKid` because it's private in `Kid`.

In the compiler's error message, `Base::Base` doesn't refer to the constructor, but to the class name `Base` injected into `Base`. Note that when the context in which it is used forces the name to be interpreted as a type, you can actually use `Base::Base` legally, like in this valid, but *vile* code:

```
class Foo {};

std::vector<Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo> v;
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4646c24664d16a4)

However, when the context in which `Base::Base` is used would allow referring to a function, it is taken to resolve to the constructor and not to the class name (C++11 [class.qual] 3.4.3.1/2)

Comment: Okay(ish), but why class Base Base::Base?

Comment: @ChrisN Ask GCC warning writers ;-) But I guess it means that `class Base` is the type in question and `Base::Base` is the name under which it was found.

Comment: Okay. Last question. Why does class Base instead von ::Base work, too (see JMA's answer)? Does this tell the compiler to use the global scope or is this just a side effect? Which of the two would be better style?

Comment: @ChrisN From my reading of the standard, `class Base` resolving the issue is actually a bug in GCC. It [doesn't help with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d684beeede36bf1), and the standard specifies that `class X` lookup of `X` is the same way as lookup of plain `X`, but only types are considered. I'm with clang on this one.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Then I stay with ::Base :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the compilter doesn't recognize Base is a class name, and recognizes it as you want to access a Base member.

This also compiles:

```
class Base {};
class Kid : private Base {};
Base instance;
class Grandkid : public Kid
{
    const class Base &GetInstance  () const
    { return instance; }
};
```

The wrong use would be use something like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    struct BaseStruct { int a; };
};
class Kid : private Base {
public:
    struct KidStruct { int a; };
};
Base instance;
class Grandkid : public Kid
{
    const class Base &GetInstance  () const
    { return instance; }

    const Kid::KidStruct kidStruct;
    const Base::BaseStruct baseStruct;
};
```

`kidStruct` has no error because inheritance is public, but `baseStruct` is inaccessible.

Comment: Do you have any idea how that line was parsed? What meaning could the compiler have given to `Base` in that statement?

Comment: Okay, now I am confused. Why does it not understand that it is class? I can (somewhat) understand that it cannot *access* the definition of the class (which then includes all methods), but what does it then help to explain "hey, this is a class"?

Comment: It actually does resolve to the class name, but to the injected (and inaccessible) one.

Comment: And  why does the class in the return ensures that it resolves it to the global scope one?